# difference keras and tf.keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, tf.keras

I found tf.keras is quite different with keras, in keras, bug occur when you use normal function instead Lambda wrapper function, bug is "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_inbound_nodes'", while in tf.keras, it is allowed use normal function and tf.keras.layers. funtion simultaneously.
keras seems use different data structure, create innode between layers.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a difference between Keras and Tf.Keras.

Keras is the standalone library implementation, on top of TensorFlow.

TF.Keras is the Keras library implemented inside the TensorFlow (and other DL frameworks in the older versions).

Everybody should choose TF.Keras, since it is better maintained, less prone to bugs, and the way to go in the future; in fact the majority of Keras developers now work on TF.Keras, including the creator Francois Chollet.

Keras standalone will not release any other major versions and will be abandoned in the future.

For all your projects and tasks that you have to solve, choose TF.Keras.

Comment: I would need some evidence to say that tf.keras is less prone to bugs, given so many changes that they made to it, this introduced a number of additional bugs that are not present in keras.

Comment: Considering that Francois Chollet himself stated that TF.Keras is less prone to errors, I would say that even though a couple of errors could have been introduced, but yes, such statements should be supported with clear evidence, I guess there was no time/not enough incentive to do so on his part.

Comment: You would need third party verification of such comment, not from the same creator as the library. And I would not say its just a couple of errors, in some cases the whole loading process is broken (see all the errors about Functional) or the large learning and computational performance differences between keras and tf.keras, or the lack of backwards compatibility (seems they do not test this at all). All these are major issues

Comment: but while keras will raise bug like: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_inbound_nodes'" and tf.keras not? from my point of view,keras seems create innodelist and outnodelist for layer, so if function is normal instead of layer, it will  raise this bug. It is that keras and tf.keras use different data structure?